# Can I create and deploy Microsoft bot with LUIS but without azure services?

Tags: azure, service, bots, azure-language-understanding

Can I create and deploy Microsoft bot without azure services?
I want to use LUIS services without azure services.
Is it possible? Alternatives for azure?

Thank you for replies in advance

Comment: What do you mean by a 'Microsoft bot'? Do you mean a bot which calls Luis?

Comment: Yes. I mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - it is possible to create a bot which uses LUIS without using the Microsoft Bot Framework -

**Using LUIS**: LUIS expose their service via HTTP endpoint. If you create an application in LUIS and create a model, you can get the intents by issuing a request to the provided endpoint. It is not directly associated with Azure. Note that in order to allow unlimited traffic to your endpoint, you will need to associate it with an Azure subscription, but you do not have to use any Azure resources.

**Microsoft Bot Framework** - In order to create a bot without using the bot framework, first let's understand what services the framework provides you with. you need:

1. Somewhere to host your bot as a service. You can use any cloud provider for this or even host it on your machine
2. Build your bot - you bot will have to implement a conversation protocol, depending on the channel for which you are writing your bot
3. Integrate with the channel for which you are building your bot for - bots for Facebook, Telegram or Skype have different protocols and need to be connected differently with these platforms. The Bot Framework simplifies this process for you. But you can just create a specific bot for your desired platform. For that, you should check the documentation for the channel which you develop for.

Comment: hmmm...
"you can get the intents by issuing a request to the provided endpoint"

How to ?

Comment: And one more thing .... 
Azure offers service to communicate with LUIS. What features should i buy to make this work ?
I asked one more question here because of reaching my limit for questions plus i see you have a good knowledge about this topic.
Thank you for your replies :)

Comment: Regarding issuing the request, I suggest you check out this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B821 starting at around minute 25, they show a live coding session of doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Regarding what you need to setup in Azure, see https://www.luis.ai/Help#CreatingKeys